# Data preparation for Machine Learning

Tags: deep-learning, data-cleaning

I am new to machine learning. I have task at hand to predict outcome of a "process" for a set of inputs. The problem is that the "process" does not produce the exact **same** output for a given set of inputs but introduces some variation, i.e., my training data for inputs *x* and output *y* looks like below

```
x11, x21, x31 -> y1
x11, x21, x31 -> y2
x11, x21, x31 -> y3
x12, x22, x32 -> y4
x12, x22, x32 -> y5
...
```

Shall I just use this data as it for training deep neural network? or some data preparation steps are required?

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,
based on your question I think that this answer already available:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889065/is-it-acceptable-to-have-the-same-input-multiple-times-in-machine-learning-with#:~:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20acceptable%20to,of%20confusing(ambiguous)%20data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889065/is-it-acceptable-to-have-the-same-input-multiple-times-in-machine-learning-with#:%7E:text=Yes%2C%20it%20is%20acceptable%20to,of%20confusing(ambiguous)%20data).
can be helpful for you.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).